# How can I prove the following equality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following equality :
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}$$

where $0 <b \leq a$.

I used the residues but I could not prove this equality

Comment: Is this a question about the programming package Mathematica, or is this a math question about how to use the residue theorem? If it is the second, then you want http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

That would be because it's false.

```
Integrate[Cos[2 t]/(a^2 Sin[t]^2 + b^2 Cos[t]^2), {t, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

`FullSimplify` it under the assumption that `0 < b <= a`, and you get `((a - b) \[Pi])/(a b (a + b))`.

Comment: +1 It's rather suggestive, that a dimensional analysis gives away something being wrong here.